# Pinned Windows Git Bash taskbar icon not respecting git-bash.exe shortcut startup directory

Tags: windows, git-bash

When I right click the Git Bash shortcut in `C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Git` 
it allows me to set a `Start in` directory.

However, if I right click Git Bash on my taskbar and pin it, close Git Bash and then reopen it via the pinned app on the taskbar, it's not respecting the startup directory I configured previously.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By pinning the opened program onto the taskbar, you end up creating another shortcut. For editing it:

- Close the app
- Hold shift
- Right click the pinned taskbar icon
- Pick Properties
- Set your startup dir

Comment: It wasn't there in that folder even when I had it pinned, I unpinned it and copied the shortcut that works into this folder but then it doesn't appear on the taskbar. It looks like Git Bash doesn't like being pinned.

Comment: I pinned git bash here and I could indeed see the icon under this folder. Which Windows version are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, version 1709. I tried it again and it's now there, and the properties include the correct start path, however it doesn't open there.

Comment: Bad news, it may be a bit tricky: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar

Comment: Damn it. I'll see what I can do. I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Does holding shift, right clicking on the taskbar icon (with the app closed), picking the Properties option and changing the startup setting work? It's described here: https://winaero.com/blog/change-a-pinned-apps-shortcut-icon-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/

Comment: Great! Refactored my answer since this method will work on any windows version. Cheers!